# How to create Toggle in Intent Configuration in WidgetKit

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

What is kind of this Intent Configuration in Widget?

[image]

Pick event can show or hidden belong state of `UISwitch`. I know it is Parent property. But, I can't find type intent to use `UISwitch`. That'll I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Type` of the parent parameter to `Boolean`:

[image]

Then for the `event` parameter set the correct relationship:

[image]